# Enforce encryption in Outlook 2010 for specific E-Mail addresses

Tags: email, encryption, microsoft-word-2010, digital-signature

There is a specific E-Mail address which I have to send data always encrypted and signed. I already configured everything, such that the E-Mails get encrypted and signed, but I often forget to turn on the encryption...

Is there a possibility to tell Outlook 2010 to send E-Mails always encrypted and signed, but only if the recipient is a specific E-Mail address?

Answer (score 0):

This question was also asked on the Microsoft Community web site:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/specify-outgoing-mail-encryption-on-a-per/445a57d4-58c9-4122-917f-5491dee3852a

One should "never say never", but it appears that this is not a native feature of Outlook 2010.  However the above link includes an answer that is a commercial plug for a third party add-in that claims to do what you want, and you may find other third-party alternatives on Google.